# How to create two separate random numbers within the same form?

Tags: vb.net

trying to make a number adding game as part of a computer science project and with the code i currently have it displays the same number in different text boxes. I would like two different random numbers displayed in separate boxes, Thanks.

```
    Dim rn As Random
    Dim number As Integer
    rn = New Random
    number = rn.Next(1, 9)
    Dim rn2 As Random
    Dim number1 As Integer
    rn2 = New Random
    number1 = rn2.Next(1, 9)



    tbxOne.Text = number.ToString
    tbxTwo.Text = number1.ToString

End Sub
```

Comment: Use *one* random instance and just call NEXT a second time.  That wont guarantee they are different - random does not mean unique

Comment: `Dim nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 8).OrderBy(Function(r) rn.Next()).Take(2).ToArray()` will give you an array of 2 different values from 1 to 8 (as in your code)  `tbxOne.Text = nums(0).ToString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create random numbers with 1 instance itself. Moreover your random numbers can be different or same.

```
Dim rn As Random
Dim number As Integer
Dim number1 As Integer

rn = New Random
number = rn.Next(1, 9)
number1 = rn.Next(1, 9)

tbxOne.Text = number.ToString
tbxTwo.Text = number1.ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating two Random instances at the same time. These numbers aren't truly random; their seed is time-dependent, so your two Randoms will have the same seed. You should use *one* Random and use its Next function every time you need a new value.

```
Dim rn As New Random
Dim number As Integer = rn.Next(1, 9)
Dim number1 As Integer = number
Do until number1 <> number
    number1 = rn.Next(1, 9)
Loop

tbxOne.Text = number.ToString
tbxTwo.Text = number1.ToString
```

There may be a more elegant solution to ensure unique numbers, but the loop will probably satisfy your needs.