# Random Picture generator giving error "reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"

Tags: vb.net

I need to develop a random picture generator as part of my project and since i'm a newbie i pinched some code of the internet, however it's throwing up the error message "reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference". This is my code:

```
      Dim randnum As random
      Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    randnum = Random.Next(30)
    pbxPicture.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Image_" & randnum.ToString())
End Sub
```

my images in my resources are named "image_0" "image_1" and so on so i hope you see what i'm trying to achieve here, if any one could assist me with this i'd be very grateful :) thanks!

Comment: you never created a `New` instance of the `Random` object and...

Comment: Your `randnum` variable is completely confused.  You need to call `Next` on an instance.

Comment: Your app will also leak if something like that is called periodically.  `GetObject()` returns a new object each time.  Store the images in an array and assign them from that array

Comment: Ironically, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40494447/1070452) does it correctly....[and this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40454973/1070452).  Since you got help on those posts, I would encourage you to take the [Tour] to see how SO works.  If your questions were answered, click the checkmark for the most helpful  to move them off the Unanswered List

Comment: Oh, missed that Plutonix already mentioned the thing about accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must [**instantiate**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77s47661.aspx) the `randnum` variable, then call [**`Next()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5(v=vs.110).aspx) on that. You also need an `Integer` variable to put the return value of `Next()` in.

For clarity I renamed the first variable to `rand` and let the integer variable have the name `randnum` instead:

```
Dim rand As New Random 'Renamed variable and added the "New" keyword.
Dim randnum As Integer = 0 'An Integer variable to hold the result of "rand.Next()".

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    randnum = rand.Next(30)
    pbxPicture.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Image_" & randnum.ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: You might also want to follow Plutonix's advice on creating an array instead.

Comment: Oh wow thanks a lot guys, sorry for the trivial question, i probably will follow Plutonix's advice as that seems to prevent me having problems further down the road, thanks again guys!

Comment: @Brandontom : No problem. We're open to any question, big or small, as long as it somewhat follows [the guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ;)